# Prevent hyphenation and use line break in block of text

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I have a custom block of text on my title page which can be longer than a single line.  By default LaTeX is hyphenating a word at the end of a line, but I want it to break on to the next line.

How do I force this to happen?

I know I can use `\\` in the text, but I'm creating a standard template for a documents and I would prefer it to handle this edge case automatically instead of having to remember to break the text manually.

E.g.

> This is my title longpiece-
>   oftext

should be

> This is my title
>   longpieceoftext

Answer (score 46):

See [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff) answer in the TeX FAQ.

Three "easy" ways to prevent hyphenation for a text block (as opposed to the whole document) are:

- Enclose the text block in a `raggedright` environment (this typesets the block raggedright and makes hyphenation very unlikely);
- Enclose the text block in a group and set `\hyphenpenalty` and `\exhyphenpenalty` to 10000;
- EDIT: Load the [hyphenat](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat) package and write `\nohyphens{(text block)}`.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\textwidth 300pt

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{raggedright}

\blindtext

\end{raggedright}

\begingroup
\hyphenpenalty 10000
\exhyphenpenalty 10000

\blindtext

\endgroup

\nohyphens{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

EDIT 2: The [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) package provides the additional commands `\nohyphenation` (which normally should be used inside a group) and `\textnohyphenation{(text)}`.

Comment: biblatex's \\[text]nohyphenation only work on complete paragraphs; they rely on \lefthyphenmin, and the value of that at the end of the paragraph is used when breaking a paragraph into lines.

Comment: I would like to point out that none of these solutions work if the `wrapfigure` is used. The text simply ignores the figure and writes on it.

Answer (score 20):

If the *longpieceoftext* s are few and easily identified, then

```
This is my title \mbox{longpieceoftext} with 
some other \mbox{ridiculouslylongtextaddition}
```

should do what you want. You will, of course, "get what you wish for, so beware": over/underfull boxes...

Comment: This may cause the text block to stick into the margin.

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, true. I think OP needs to clarify a bit exactly what he's trying to do. For example, this answer plus \raggedright might fill the bill...

Answer (score 8):

You must use:

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

Read this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document)

Comment: This would prevent more than only one text block, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command:

```
\raggedright
```

or the environment:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\end{flushleft}
```

[§ Paragraph alignment](//wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Paragraph_alignment)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution:

```
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{new}{\nohyphens{#1}}
```

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. For code-blocks indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent names from being hyhenated then in the preamble write `\hyphenation{Verylongname anothername namex namey etcetera}`.

I think you need the `babel` package for this.

Comment: But note, this would prevent the given words from being hyphenated everywhere in the document not only in one special text block.