# Unwanted line breaks in middle of words

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating the entire document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document)

I have a two-column article with custom margins.  In some points of the text, line breaks occur in the middle of words.  For instance, "results" appears as "re-[break]sults" although no hypen is typed in the word.  I have several instances of this in the same text.

Is there a hint I can provide to tell `latex` not to insert line breaks in the middle of words?

Comment: That's the automatic hyphenation that helps to get a good justification of the paragraphs; it's particularly useful in double column format.

Comment: I'm aware it helps with good justification in a narrow-column setting.  However, I thought it was considered bad style.

Comment: @lockstep: thanks, the `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` solved my problem.

Comment: Multiple solutions are described in the excellent question [How to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating the entire document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document). I ended up using suggestion #2 in the accepted answer (`\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`).

Comment: On the contrary, it's perfectly good style.

Comment: Ok, in this case we close this question as a duplicate.