# Justify text in moderncv cover letter

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv, letters

I am writing a cover letter and CV using `moderncv`. Everything works fine so far, but the text in the cover letter is not justified. I think it is good that it is not hyphenated, but it would look much nicer if the text was justified.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\recipient{Prof.\ Dr.\ Foo Bar}{}
\opening{Dear Professor Dr.\ Bar,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae}

\makelettertitle
\lipsum[1]
\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2009--present}{PhD Student}{here}{and}{there}{}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Add the following to your document preamble, after loading the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) style (`classic`):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
  {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
  {\@opening}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

[image: output]

The above patch just removes the necessary `\raggedright` from the template at the correct location (just before calling `\@opening`).

Comment: @Werner Works great. But that resulted many hyphenation in my text. Is there any way to fully justify (like in word processors) ???

Comment: @TheKojuEffect: Try adding `\makeatletter\\hyphenpenalty=\@M\makeatletter` to your document preamble. This should assign an large enough (infinite) *penalty* to automatically hyphenate any words at a line break, effectively removing the ability to hyphenate in the document. For more on penalties, see [What are penalties and which ones are defined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51263/5764) If this doesn't work, see [How to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating the entire document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5036/5764)

Answer (score 31):

You can simply include:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

and right after `\makelettertitle` put:

```
\justify
```

Works fine for me both with classic and with casual.

Comment: I believe this is the simplest answer here. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to insert an extra newline after `\makelettertitle`.

Answer (score 17):

Just fix the "bug" in moderncv templates.
If you use banking style, go to `moderncvstylebanking.sty` and change

```
% opening
\raggedright%
\@opening\\[1.5em]%
```

into

```
% opening
{\raggedright%
\@opening\\[1.5em]}%
```

Note that this simply enclose the `raggedright` command, so it won't affect the entire document from this point onwards.
You can do the same for each of the other styles.

Comment: Even if Wener's answer works, I believe this is a better, perhaps correct, way of doing it.

Comment: The fact that `\raggedright` is not enclosed in a group with `\@opening` is actually not a bug, it's the intended design. AFAIK, the convention for letters is not to justify the text, but to have it flushed left. Obviously (and thankfully!), some people might have a different preference than the "conventional wisdom", and an easy way to select what you prefer would probably be a welcome addition to `moderncv`.

Comment: @Xavier If you are correct, then the "correct" way of doing so would be to apply 'raggedright' separately for the opening the the body of the letter, and not tying the two.

Answer (score 10):

On ModernCV version 2.0, the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76018/31494) provided by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) needs to be updated to:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
  {\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
  {\@opening}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect this. There's no need for an additional answer.

Comment: yeah, i tried to comment on it, but didn't have enough "brownie points" for a comment! sorry, SE rules apparently.

Answer (score 2):

I have a not so elegant solution using `\minipage`. That works fine for the casual style but it should work for the other ones as well.

Before `\begin{document}`, add:

```
\newlength{\currentparskip}
```

Then, when writing the letter, after the `\makelettertitle` command, put:

```
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value of paragraph spacing
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} %create minipage
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value    

      TEXT OF THE LETTER

    \end{minipage}

\makeletterclosing

\clearpage
```

The paragraph spacing is zero in the `\minipage`, so one has to restore the value so that the text spacing would be ok.

Answer (score -1):

The current solutions didn't work for me. Here's what did:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

And then after `\makelettertitle` I added:

```
\justifying
```

Worked on both `casual` and `classic` styles on Overleaf.