# How to configure (tweak) babel's hyphenation?

Tags: babel, hyphenation

I found out that I can tweak hyphenation settings by writing:

```
\righthyphenmin=6
\lefthyphenmin=6
\usepackage{hyphenat}
```

I like this, because it hyphenates only *really* long words, leaving all others intact. But when I do `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, hyphenation goes back to default settings.

I understand that when I load `babel`, [it starts handling all the hyphenation](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff) and my settings mentioned above are not used anymore. How can I have a similar configuration while using `babel`? Maybe I can use some option, so that it will not change hyphenation settings?

(Side note: Normally I wouldn't use `babel`, but I need translated titles and captions for figures and lists.)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5039/17809

Comment: To avoid hyphenation, use `\usepackage{microtype}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `babel` documention states:

> The macro `\<lang>hyphenmins` is used to store the values of the
>   `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin`. Redefine this macro to set your
>   own values, with two numbers corresponding to these two parameters.

So that would be:

```
\renewcommand\ngermanhyphenmins{66}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

```
\usepackage[ngerman=nohyphenation]{babel}
```

Comment: This setting won't let LaTeX hyphenate really long words, will it?

Comment: It does, using the `hyphenat` package.