# Allow line breaks in date ranges?

Tags: hyphenation, datetime

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,paper=14.8cm:21cm,BCOR=10mm,DIV=12,parskip=half]
{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Markus hat den Krieg überstanden, hat Zahnmedizin studiert und wurde
Zahnarzt in Bonn. Aus der Ehe mit Manuela Schmidt (1905–1989) gingen vier
Kinder hervor: Otto (1926–1995), Marta (geb. 1931), Fritz (1933–1999) und
Sonja (geb. 1942).
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Text as rendered from above code]

Desired output:

[image: Text rendering as desired]

To avoid overly long lines, I'd like to tell LaTeX that it's OK to line break
date ranges.

Comment: I think according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/, something like `(1905-{\allowbreak}1989)` would do the trick.

Comment: if you use the minus sign you can replace it with `"=`; also works for combined words like `Mehrzweck"=Küchenmaschine`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you replace all instances of "`–`" (hardcoded en-dash) with "`--\allowbreak`". (Aside: if your document has hard-coded em-dashes, you may want to replace them with "`---\allowbreak`".)  The "`\allowbreak`" part is needed if you compile your document with LuaLaTeX; it's not strictly necessary with pdfLaTeX (though it doesn't hurt either).

For the paragraph at hand, one of the three possible new line breaks will be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,paper=14.8cm:21cm,BCOR=10mm,DIV=12,parskip=half]
{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Markus hat den Krieg überstanden, hat Zahnmedizin studiert und wurde
Zahnarzt in Bonn. Aus der Ehe mit Manuela Schmidt (1905--\allowbreak 1989) 
gingen vier Kinder hervor: Otto (1926--\allowbreak 1995), Marta (geb. 
1931), Fritz (1933--\allowbreak 1999) und Sonja (geb. 1942).
\end{document}
```

Comment: I feel like there was a way to automate this with `\newunicodechar` or something

Comment: Why do you recommend replacing the hard coded dash `–` with `--`?

Comment: @feklee - The `\allowbreak` directive is necessary if the document is compiled under LuaLaTeX. With pdfLaTeX, it's not required, but it doesn't hurt either. I'll add a note to the answer to point out this distinction.

Comment: What do you think about avoiding the hard-coding via `\newcommand{\daterange}[2]{#1--\allowbreak#2}` or something similar?

Comment: @Ruben -- Sure, that'll work very well.

Comment: @Ruben Try this on for size: `\def\daterange#1{\daterangei#1\stop}\def\daterangei#1-#2\stop{#1--\allowbreak#2}...\daterange{1926-1995}`. (Untested, but should work. A more robust implementation is possible with `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` from expl3.)

Comment: @SeanAllred -- I like the interface design of your version is way better ;)