# Turning off hyphenation and redefining the typesetting of italics and bold

Tags: macros, context, hyphenation

I want to emulate under ConTeXt the manuscript format provided by the `sffms` LaTeX package: http://www.mcdemarco.net/sffms/

It provides, roughly, these features:

- Double spaced manuscript
- 12-point mono-spaced, no hyphenation
- One inch margins
- Running headers in the form of 'Author/TITLE/page-number
- A title page with the title in the center of the page and other info

It has other features, like converting smart quotes into simple quotes and also redefining commands to replace italics with underlined text.

My problems right now are:

- I can't seem to deactivate hyphenation in ConTeXt and don't know how.
- I would need to redefine commands in order to emulate the behaviour of underlining italics and bold.

This is how I changed the typeface of the entire text, unable to turn off hyphenation:

```
\usetypescript[courier][uc]
\setupbodyfont[courier,mono,12pt]
```

If I do like this, hyphenation gets turned off, but I am not sure this is a good solution:

```
\definetypeface [courier]  [rm]  [serif] [courier]
\usetypescript[courier][uc]
\setupbodyfont[courier,rm,12pt]
```

As for the redefining the commands, I would like to see an example which does it 'the right way' (what to redefine).

Comment: I do not use ConTeXt, but have you tried all solutions mentioned here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5036 ? If you do not want any hyphenation, I would recommend to set your document `\raggedright` as this will prevent many ugly spacing issues.

Answer (score 2):

To turn off hyphenation use

```
\setupalign [nothyphenated]
```

See [ConTeXt wiki - Hyphenation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Hyphenation).

To typeset text in bold and underline you can define:

```
\definehighlight
  [important]
  [style={\bf\setbar[underbar]}]
```

Then use `\important{…}` to highlight the text.

Comment: You don’t need `\groupedcommand` when you use `\setbar` to enable the `\underbar` command: `\definehighlight[important][style={\bf\setbar[underbar]}]`

Comment: Oh my, how could I have overlooked the nothyphenated option in setupalign? I read the wiki page, but somehow I just skipped it...

Comment: @Metafox That's right and I believe it's a bit cleaner as well. I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: Can I use this mecanism to redefine the command 'emph', for example?

Comment: @J.A.Rubio Yes, but note that overwriting existing macros can lead to confusion and misbehaviour. So in case of doubt rather than overwriting existing macros just create your own version to be on the safe side.

Comment: My aim is to redefine the command 'emph' so that in manuscript mode it underlines the text, and in normal mode it does whatever emph should do (set the text in italics).

Comment: @J.A.Rubio You can use modes for that (check the manual or wiki). Furthermore, it's better to ask a single question about one particular issue.