# interword spacing latex in a table

Tags: spacing

I have a table with words separated by commas. Latex puts additional spaces in between these words which look a bit odd.

```
  \begin{table*}[!tb]
\begin{center}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{tabular} {|p{0.8in}|p{2.75in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.3in}| }
\hline
{\bf Features} & {\bf Feat Selection} &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bf F\_score } \\ \hline
&&&favor&against&average \\ \hline
\bf Aaaaaaaa & uuuuuuuu,  bnnnnn,  general\_ddd,  llll\_ddd,  sddddddddd\_combined\_ddd & none & 0.71&0.64 & 0.67\\ \hline
\bf Abbbbbbb & uuuuuuuu, bnnnnn,  general\_ddd,  llll\_ddd,  sddddddddd\_combined\_ddd & none &0.73&0.66 & 0.69\\ \hline
\bf Ffffffffff & uuuuuuuu, bnnnnn,  general\_ddd,  llll\_ddd,  stttttttt\_combined\_dtt, POS\_bmmmmm & crrrrrrrrr &  0.55&0.57&0.56\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{scriptsize}
\begin{small}
\caption{\label{results} Best performing model.}
\end{small}
\end{center}
\end{table*}


\begin{table*}[!htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{tabular} {|p{0.8in}|p{2.15in}|p{2.15in}|r|}
\hline
{\bf Topic} &  \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {\bf Seed Hhhhhhhh } & \bf Tttttt  \\ \hline
\bf kkkkkkkk &  \#YayFeminism, \#YesAllWomen, \#FeministsAreBeautiful & \#AntiFeminism, \#AntiFeminist, \#WomenAgainstFeminism  &  4446 \\ \hline
\bf Hhhhhhh Cccccc  & \#ImWithHer, \#HillYes, \#ITrustHillary, & \#StopHillary, \#HillaryForPrison, \#OhHillNo & 8529 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{scriptsize}
```

This is what I get
[image]
This has additional spaces in Feat selection column and seed column. How can I remove these to have normal spacing.

Comment: Welcome :).  Note, I have **added another suggestion**, at the end of the post.  This one would change the table a bit, but you may like it better.  See the post I link to for a little more, and for docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:   Turn off hyphenation only for select text, full example.**

This seems to be happening because Latex is struggling to format the line, and in the shortened space in a table cell the hyphenation may not make it any better.  You can

- Tweak hyphenation.  One good way of doing it is by using the package [`hyphenat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat?lang=en).  Then you can turn off hyphenation for select parts of text via `\nohyphens{text}`. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document) for far more on this, and for other ways (with shortcomings but that may work perfectly in this case).
- Then, the text may not look nice. To improve that you can flush it to one side, for example with `\raggedright` to left-justify, see [Paragraph alignment](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Paragraph_alignment). You can also use the `\begin{flushleft} ... \end{flushleft}` environment, but this is going to be unwieldy with table and cells.

---

Example of using the package and `\raggedright`.  Note -- I found that the mere use of the packages improves hyphenation of your examples, by its defaults.  There are other settings in the package that you can tweak.

```
\usepackage{hyphenat}

% first table exactly the same but looking better with the package

\begin{table*}[!htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{tabular} {|p{0.8in}|p{2.15in}|p{2.15in}|r|} \hline
{\bf Topic} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {\bf Seed Hhhhhhhh } & \bf Tttttt \\ \hline 
    \bf kkkkkkkk   
    & \raggedright \nohyphens{
      \#YayFeminism, \#YesAllWomen, \#FeministsAreBeautiful}
    & \raggedright \nohyphens{ 
      \#AntiFeminism, \#AntiFeminist, \#WomenAgainstFeminism}  
    &  4446 \\ \hline
    \bf Hhhhhhh Cccccc
    & \raggedright \#ImWithHer, \#HillYes, \#ITrustHillary,
    & \raggedright \#StopHillary, \#HillaryForPrison, \#OhHillNo 
    & 8529 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

I've broken the lines for readability here.

[image: table example]

---

**Added note**

I'd recommend to look into the `booktabs` package, demonstrated in [this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380743/latex-multicolumn-vertical-center/36381250#36381250), for example. Its use is very simple. It is considered to produce more professional looking tables. (There is some taste involved, of course.) Your second table would look like this

[image: table with booktabs]

The only changes to code are: add `\usepackage{booktabs}`, then replace all of `\hline` with:

- `\toprule` for the header line)
- `\midrule` for others (may not need all of them!)
- `\bottomrule` for the last one

Also, remove vertical lines.  They seldom help, and here your text nicely lines up forming a visual guide.

Answer (score 2):

After some fiddling with the formatting for me, `\RaggedRight` from the package [`ragged2e`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/ms/ragged2e.pdf) worked better as it does not totally suppress hyphenation.

```latex
\begin{tabular} {|p{0.8in}|>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5in}|p{2.15in}|r|}
```