# Long blank space in the middle of paragraph

Tags: spacing, formatting, paragraphs

I have this problem on of my paragraphs in my document. There is a large blank space in between the first and the second word in the paragraph. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn, english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\pretolerance=10000
\tolerance=2000 
\emergencystretch=10pt

\begin{document}
\subsection{Haptic Devices}
\paragraph{}
Haptic interfaces are devices that uses the modality of touch for input and        output in interaction. These devices provide better immersion and presence in    virtual environments\cite{Tsalamal}, but also bridges issues of use when other sensory modalities are unavailable, such as vision for the blind\cite{Sjostrom}. Haptic devices that are either attached, or with limited or no direct contact are currently being explored \cite{Tsalamal}. Devices that are attached or provide limited contact allow more freedom but limited force rendering. A number of non-contact devices have promising, but share the issue of some of the limited-contact devices which is the restricted workspace\cite{Tsalamal}. 
\end{document}
```

With this code the output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is a large gap between the first and the second word. Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: It may comes from the `\pretolerance=10000`. Try to comment it.

Comment: When I commented it out the large space disappears, but I wanted to use `\pretolerance=10000` to remove the hyphenations from the text.

Comment: And why do you want to suppress all hyphenation operations?

Comment: Try `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` to suppress hypenations.

Comment: In my opinion it looks better without them

Comment: I suggest that you keep the hyphenation, but load the package `microtype` instead. You will then reduce the numbers of hyphenation to a minimum, unless you write a lot of log words.  Big, white spaces in the text is ugly, and reduce the readability of your text. If you insist not to use hyphenation, you should set your text ragged right.

Comment: More often than not, good typography is about striking a balance between conflicting criteria for what may 'look good'. The  preference ordering you impose -- "[I don't want hyphens because] in my opinion [the text] looks better without them" -- precludes any kind of balance. If you absolutely don't want hyphens, you have to accept that other typographic problems will show up, e.g., large and highly distracting inter-word gaps. Eventually, you will come to the conclusion that disallowing all hyphenation is not better after all.

Comment: do you really have to avoid hyphenation????, especially in a two column document that will mean that ugly white spaces are inevitable.  It's going against several hundred years of typographic practice to say that over stretched spaces are better than the occasional hyphenated word.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If there would be a way to just hyphenate certain words, for example if the words were longer than 8 characters and that at least half the word were on one side of the hyphenation then I would want to have them in my text. But when words with 4 character gets hyphenated with 2 characters on each side (which there is a lot of examples of in my current document) then I prefer not to have them in the document.

Comment: you can specify the minimum amount of characters to left and right of the break (which are 2 and 3 in the default english patterns so a 4-letter word will not break) (`\lefthyphenmin=6` would make it 6)

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you! I will try it out.

Comment: but as I say if you are typing in English and 4-letter words are breaking then something is wrong with your setup

Comment: I tried adding `\lefthyphenmin=6` to the document, but it still breaks a word after 2 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete `\pretolerance=10000` and `\tolerance=2000`, and to suppress hyphenation to the entire document, use `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` (see this question: [How to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating the entire document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document)).

Comment: I wrote \usepackage[english]{hyphenat} because I saw that the OP uses babel and the text is written in english

Comment: `\usepackage[english]{hyphenat}` gives me an error

Comment: You're right, I corrected the answer

Comment: When I change that I get the following layout: https://gyazo.com/d5c445a0396a9188a2725d134d8d96b8 . Which certainly looks better, but there is still a gap on row 3. I guess there is no way to make it perfect.

Comment: @Alessio By the way, I think you should ask me to post an answer if my comments solve the problem instead of posting your own answer containing all I said in comments, just a few minutes before.

Comment: @martin36 The gap in line 3 comes from the fact that you disabled hyphenation.

Comment: @martin36 The only way to avoid this gap is to allow hyphenation

Comment: Alright, then I know. Thank you for all the good answers.

Comment: @Jerome I tryed to solve it on my own and then I searched for references in other answers. Why don't you have posted your own answer instead? And above all why are you saying this?