# Geometry margin causing tasks alignment issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment, geometry, tasks

For some reason, if one sets a margin using the geometry package, this causes an alignment problem with the tasks package:

MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,tasks}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=2cm}
\NewTasks[counter-format={tsk[a])}]{problems}[\item](4)

\begin{document}\raggedright

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Prove the following:
    \begin{problems}(4)
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \end{problems}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Interestingly, at certain values, e.g. margin = 1in, there is no problem. But at other values, such as margin = 0.5cm, which is smaller than a 1in margin, there are problems. This eliminates a minimum width issue. What is the solution to this?

Comment: `\raggedright` does some magic internally, and is being responsible for the issue you see.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this but maintain raggedright?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One should reset `\@rightskip`. Imho the tasks package should do it. So make a bug report:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}


\geometry{a4paper, margin=2cm}
\NewTasks[counter-format={tsk[a])}]{problems}[\item](4)

\begin{document}\raggedright

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Prove the following:
    \begingroup
    \makeatletter 
    \@rightskip=0pt
    \begin{problems}(4)
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \item $x$
        \end{problems}
      \endgroup         
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\AtBeginEnvironment{problems}{\setlength\@rightskip{0pt}}` (requires `etoolbox`).

Comment: I added something to my tracker so I don't forget: https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks/issues/10

Comment: Would there be any way to wrap this in an environment? E.g. (with xParse) \NewDocumentEnvironment{dummyEnvironment}{}
  {\begingroup
\makeatletter 
    \@rightskip=0pt
 \problems(2)}
  {\endgroup\endproblems}                  Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Could a solution with `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` package be acceptable?

*EDIT:* Ulrike has already given the perfect answer but I'd like to add TeXnician's suggestion (`\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`) to my original answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,tasks}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=2cm}
\NewTasks[counter-format={tsk[a])}]{problems}[\item](4)
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}\RaggedRight
    \blindtext
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \blindtext Prove the following:
        \begin{problems}(4)
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
        \end{problems}
    \end{enumerate}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Moreover, as egreg suggested to me in chat, another simple solution could be justifying only the `problems` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,tasks}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=2cm}
\NewTasks[counter-format={tsk[a])}]{problems}[\item](4)
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}\raggedright
    \blindtext
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \blindtext Prove the following:
        \begin{justify}
        \begin{problems}(4)
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
            \item $x$
        \end{problems}
        \end{justify}
    \end{enumerate}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

The output is more or less the same as before:

[image]

Comment: Problem is the hyphenation that occurs with that. If there is a way around that, we might have a solution!

Comment: Hi! Please leave it up, someone else might know how to fix the hyphenation problem.

Comment: But that is pretty close anyway, thanks very much!

Comment: For hyphenation https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document could help.

Comment: @Pravin See the link TeXnician posted

Comment: @TeXnician +1, I didn't know that :)