# Words getting cut off in LaTeX when new line starts

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, text

In my LaTeX document words are cut automatically whenever a new line is due. It is not able to wrap/justify in normal sentences. Here is an example:

[image]

This is happening throughout the document. Is there any way to fix it? I googled a lot for hours and concluded that it is normal by default for all users. I am using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Overleaf example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/dscbvttynnfh

Is there a way to have new words on a new line only?

Comment: It's normal to hyphenate text, and that's part of justifying text. There are situations when you would want to avoid it (and use a ragged right column instead), but this seems very inappropriate for the kind of text this seems to be. I think you should look at how other texts look that are in the same category as what you are writing.

Comment: Related: [How to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating the entire document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5036/134144)

Comment: You might try using the micro type package which can stretch or shrink a font’s characters a tiny amount as well as let some punctuation extend slightly past the right margin to optically maintain full justification. This works best with pdflatex and least with xelatex.

Comment: Just to make sure that any non-native speakers understand: "cut-off" would imply that the rest of the word is missing.  Hyphenation (which is happening here) is when the rest of the word is on the next line of text.

Comment: By dint of seeing bad typography with immense spaces between words for years, one ends up believing that it is the best practice. Do not remove the hyphens, it looks much better as it is now.

Comment: As @Fran said, this is **not** wrong, and unless you are **absolutely required** by some weird rule (in which case see leandriis's comment above), leave it as it is.

Comment: @Joseph although I agree with you and Fran and pst, I think saying 'don't do this' in three different comments is not very welcoming towards a new user - I am sure you have good intentions (e.g., promoting good typography) but it might come across as rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @leandriis that link helped a lot.Thanks @pst

1. I had tried this earlier `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`

Using the above code solves the underlying issue.
[image]

But causes a random alignment issue in the 5th line.

2.

```
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
```

This code solved all the issues.
[image]
Thanks a lot all.

Comment: You pretty much deactivated what defines LaTeX: Good Typesetting. You might as well use Word.

Comment: If you really want to prevent hyphenation, set the text ragged right. Otherwise you don't solve any issues at all - on the contrary, you create them (eg, the 3rd and 4th lines are definitely horrid).