# How to justify text after no hyphenation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

For write a text without hyphenation I use `\package[none]{hyphenation}`. 
When I apply this package, the text does not adjust to the page margins. 
What command I should apply for justify text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please show us _how_ the text does not adjust to the margins? It should. Show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with an example paragraph that is not justified.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `\sloppy`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
Text that fills up a line but with a long unhyphenatble word,
abababababababababab, at the end of the first line.

\lipsum[1]

\sloppy

Text that fills up a line but with a long unhyphenatble word,
abababababababababab, at the end of the first line.

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I have tried to post an image of the result but failed (I've failed before. I tried the post image icon for my file hyphenatprob.pdf but it does nothing). Run the MWE to see what the result is.

i took a liberty and add image of result of above mwe:

[image]

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for adding the output of the MWE. How did you do it? I have tried on several occasions, also for external MWE code, but failed. I work on the Ubuntu OS but am not adept at moving file contents around.

Comment: first i compile your mwe and from sumatra (my pdf previewer)  with sipping tool cut area of interest, locally store it as png  image. then  i add it to answer with clicking on icon for image (right of `{}` icon), which guide me further to load stored file. unfortunately i'm not familiar with ubunto os, so i don't know the name for similar tool as is `snipping tool` in windows os.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to programmable typesetting.  Just a couple of quick questions/observations.  I expect the package name is improved by using `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`, see [CTAN page for {hyphenat}](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat?lang=en). \LaTeX presumes "full justification" as the desired formatting.

Very brief example here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[25]

\end{document}
```

This is "borrowed" from [Joel Berger's Tex Stack Exchange Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5037/134574).

This is the output.

[image]

Let's see if this addresses what you're asking.

Comment: I presume OP's actually seeing an over/underfull box and is assuming that the text is not justified, thus I asked for a MWE.

Comment: @!Phelype Oleinik.  Perfect!  Thanks.  I'd enjoy learning how you got the specific html page location.

Comment: Right below the post there is a `share` button. Click it and a link to the specific answer will appear :)