# Statistics in TexShop does not count words in tables

Tags: tables, texshop, word-count, statistics

I am finished with a scientific paper for a conference, but it does not contain the requested 7000 words. For this reason I have changed my figures with a lot of text into tables.

The statistics under Texshop gives the following:
current with all tables
words 6431
lines 1018
Characters 51739

However, if I remove one table (171 words) I get the following result:
Words 6431
Lines 1000
Characters 51721

Texshop doesn't count the words in tables, is this normal? Does anyone have a suggestion for me that the words in tables are counted?

Thanks in advance and greetings

Comment: Are you sure the 7000 words is a minimum? Ususally conferences give you a maximum, but you can submit a shorter text if you want (but this may be different for the various research fields).

Comment: Sorry for the confusing the maximum is 7000 words

Comment: So then there is no problem, because you have 6431 words, which is less than 7000? Or are you afraid that the conference will count the words in tables and that this will be more than 7000? In this case you are probably fine, I have never seen a conference _actually_ counting words and rejecting submissions that are too long, unless it is very clear that the limit is exceeded.

Comment: OK, I see thank you for your support. But I really want to know the right amount of words in my document. So is there a feature problem with the counting in TexShop?

Comment: With the pdf use chrome or ms word to open it. Both count words. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595275/161015