# Getting the inserted article's title & author as its chapter-title & chapter-author in book class

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titles, books, author

I am trying to make a science magazine (free ebook) that will contain a collection of science and math articles of different authors.
So far, I have come with this MWE using the package `docmute`:

### main.tex

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !BIB program = biblatex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
% \setlist[itemize]{label*={\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\textbullet}}      % due to the Bangla fonts
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in, 8.5in}, margin=0.8in, headheight=14.72pt]{geometry}
\linespread{1.15}

% For a bilingual document        % The font is available here: https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html                
 \usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, 
             banglattfont=Kalpurush]{latexbangla}
 %activate polyglossia
 \setdefaultlanguage[numerals=Bengali,
 changecounternumbering=true]{bengali}
 %number all levels
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
     \setotherlanguage{english}
%..............
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}                              % clear all header and footer fields
  \lhead{\href{<url>}{Magaize Website}}
  \cfoot{\thepage}    
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}

% \usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, language=english, autolang=other]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{ref.bib}

\allowdisplaybreaks 

% \tolerance=1    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177179/114006
% \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
% \hyphenpenalty=10000
% \hbadness=10000

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Article}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  
\title{Collection of Articles}
\author{Edior}
\date{}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents  
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Article 1 Title}
\input{article1}
% \chapter{Article 2 Title}
% \input{article2}
\end{document}
```

### article1.tex

```
% Contains the same preamble for the purpose of individual compilation (which is ignored while compiling main.tex)
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{ \lipsum[1][5] }
\end{figure}
\title{Title 1}
\author{Author 1}
\date{}
\maketitle
% \newpage
\section{section 1}
\lipsum 
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[1][4-6] 
\end{document}
```

Now I like to optimize the structure and set up the chapter name and chapter author name to its corresponding article title and author automatically. And thus, the article and its author should appear on ToC.

How should I do it? Also, is there any dedicated package or document class, or template which can easily provide my desired output?

Comment: Check if [combine](https://ctan.javinator9889.com/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf) is enough for you

Comment: I tried it yesterday. But it was giving errors. And later in the chat, @Ulrike Fischer told me that it is not compatible with current latex.

Comment: What a pity. Then run  `texdoc  paper`.  It is a brief manual mostly in german, but you can switch from `article` to  `paper` whitout problems, and  `journal`  class is just to mix `paper`s.