# \emergencystretch doesn't work when using AltaCV class

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, altacv

I'm very new to LaTeX, apologies if this question is silly.

I'm trying to make my document such that it has minimal hyphenation caused by linebreaks. Instead I would like each line to be stretched to fill the entire column width, if necessary. I tried what [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177179) suggested, but setting `\emergencystretch` to any value didn't have any effect at all when using the AltaCV document class; below is the output of my MWE:

[image: Output of MWE using AltaCV document class]

The strange thing is if I use `\documentclass{article}` instead of `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,withhyper]{altacv}`, it outputs the desired result (i.e. no "ragged" edges):

[image: Desired output, obtained using documentclass{article}]

**My question:** How do I obtain the desired result (2nd pic) while using the AltaCV class?

**Setup:**

- lualatex with latexmk, Win10
- [altacv.cls](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV/blob/main/altacv.cls) file in same directory as `main.tex`; no other file required for MWE.
- MWE in `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,withhyper, ragged2e]{altacv}
% \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}

\tolerance=1000
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo

\begin{itemize}
    \item lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
\end{itemize}
\switchcolumn
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well obviously the text is set with \raggedright.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i like AltaCV for their macros. And yes, using `\let\raggedright\relax` is what I wanted, thanks! I wasn't aware of what the command did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole class is designed for ragged right setting. It is probably better to choose a different class if you want a justified design,

However `\raggedright` is used in multiple places in the class file, you could remove them from your copy of the class file, or globally disable it via a definition such as
`\let\raggedright\relax` for example.