# New line instead of word-breaking

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent hyphenation and use line break in block of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/prevent-hyphenation-and-use-line-break-in-block-of-text)

When some word at the end of sentence does not fit in the line - I would like it to be moved to the new line, and not marked with `-` in half of it and then moved to new line.

For example: "Some sentence that have some-[line_break_here]-longword." - I would like otherwise: ""Some sentence that have [line_break_here] somelongword."

There must be an option to set this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Prevent hyphenation and use line break in block of text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5001/5764), [How to prevent LaTeX from line-breaking a phrase?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29257/5764)

Comment: For one-off cases, using `\mbox{somelongword}` would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

if this word is never to be broken, `\hyphenation{somelongword}` in the preamble will keep it from being hyphenated, but it may still just hang off the end, depending on the rest of the text in the paragraph.

the `microtype` package does make line breaks nicer, but i can't give an easy example either.

in desperation, wrap

```
\begin{sloppypar}
....
\end{sloppypar}
```

around the paragraph, but only as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Please, simply use `\usepackage{microtype}`. This package improves the ability of LaTeX to deal with such cases a lot.

Comment: Please, could you write some example that uses microtype package to deal with my question?

Comment: @Teddy Just give it a try. You are aware that you get the manual of nearly any package by typing `texdoc packagename` on the command line?

Comment: @Keks I guess the OP just wants a very simplified example, or at least a pointer: the `microtype` doc is just 206 pages long :-)