# LaTeX Macro for "code" style, underscore package and hyphenation

Tags: macros, hyphenation, typewriter

I'm looking for a way to nicely set code inside my document.  I used `\def\code#1{{\texttt{#1}}}`, but it still allows the text to be hyphenated. To prevent that, I tried the advise from [Prevent hyphenation and use line break in block of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/prevent-hyphenation-and-use-line-break-in-block-of-text) and tried `\def\code#1{{\mbox{\texttt{#1}}}}`, but then the font size is lost when I write, for example, `T_{\code{FOO}}`. Unfortunately, the `\nohyphens{...}` solution clashed with some other package (as I understand it) and the `\hyphenpenalty 10000` solution produced no changes.

While preparing the MWE I found that the hyphenation only happens after underscores.

It can't be that hard to get what I want, or is it?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\code#1{{\texttt{#1}}}
%\def\code#1{{\mbox{\texttt{#1}}}}

\usepackage[strings]{underscore}

\begin{document}

I really like to use \code{assert()}. Still,
\code{assertions_that_should_never_fail_even_if_they_stick_out()} 
should not be hyphenated. I know some long words: 
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis,
parastratiosphecomyia stratiosphecomyioides,
pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism,
floccinaucinihilipilification,
subdermatoglyphic,
squirrelled,
abstentious and 
rotavator.

Function \code{FOO} runs in time $T_{\code{FOO}}$, not $T_{FOO}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using verbatim text: `\verb+Here is my code.+` Any character (except `*`) can be used to delimit the verbatim text, as long as it doesn't appear in the text itself, obviously.

Comment: I already tried that. I get `LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.`

Comment: @egreg: of course text should not stick out, I just want no hyphenation in `\code{}` but warnings in the log. Your solution works fine! Thanks again.

Comment: @egreg: I'm grateful for the solution, but now it takes always 5 cycles to compile the document (pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)). It used to be done in max. 3. Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand why you'd want long blocks of text sticking out in the margin.

However, here's a way; I avoided `underscore` for a safer method accomplishing the same result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % better underscore
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\newcommand\code[1]{\texttt{#1}}

%% This code substitutes underscore.sty
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~{\ifmmode\sb\else\textunderscore\fi}
}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`_=\active}
%% end

\begin{document}

I like to use \code{assert()}. Still,
\code{assertions_that_should_never_fail_even_if_they_stick_out()}
should not be hyphenated. I know some long words:
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis,
parastratiosphecomyia stratiosphecomyioides,
pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism,
floccinaucinihilipilification,
subdermatoglyphic,
squirrelled,
abstentious and
rotavator.

Function \code{FOO} runs in time $T_{\code{FOO}}$, not $T_{FOO}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `\textnhtt` (again from `hyphenat`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % better underscore
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\DeclareRobustCommand\code[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\texttt
  \else
    \expandafter\textnhtt
  \fi{#1}%
}

%% This code substitutes underscore.sty
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~{\ifmmode\sb\else\textunderscore\fi}
}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`_=\active}
%% end

\begin{document}

I like to use \code{assert()}. Still,
\code{assertions_that_should_never_fail_even_if_they_stick_out()}
should not be hyphenated. I know some long words:
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis,
parastratiosphecomyia stratiosphecomyioides,
pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism,
floccinaucinihilipilification,
subdermatoglyphic,
squirrelled,
abstentious and
rotavator.

Function \code{FOO} runs in time $T_{\code{FOO}}$, not $T_{FOO}$.

\end{document}
```

Note that with `amsmath` the subscript size is chosen correctly.